# Am I allowed to pray salah and perform other Islamic rituals if I come in contact with my semen

Tags: pornography

I am a 16 year old muslim. I watched porn and mastrubated for the past 3 years. Now I stopped however I mastrubated in many places within my house (chair, bed and etc). I performed ghusl but I didn't clean the semen on these locations where I mastrubated. I don't want to tell this to my parents as well. It been 3 days since I last mastrubated. If I come in contact with the semen can I pray salah and perform other Islamic rituals

Comment: If you add the tag masturbation, the tags taharah or najis you'd find answers covering your inquiry. The last time I covered a similar question is only yesterday. I suppose you are able to do a bit of research.

Answer (score -1):

Assalm o Alaikum
Indeed it is a sin that should every one avoid it...
But now as you are regretting of your sin, so ALLAH Almighty is most merciful..
He will surely forgive you...
And if you want to pray, you should pray in masjid.. If it is not possible than at home but at a place where there is no dirt like you told semen.
Because it is compulsory for prayer to be offered at clean and pure place...
Jzk

Comment: Since it's been four days since I last mastrubated most probably all the semen should have dried so if I come in contact with it, is it fine? (for example after I do wudu to pray magrib my sister and mom are using the musala, so until they finish I wait on the bed. Is this act going to reject my prayer ). Another problem is that everyone who comes to my house and the people in my house always come in contact with the places where I mastrubated and they are not aware of this. So will there prayer be reacted as well. Please help me out.